# Can't compile with ICU library - undefined reference to 'u_strlen_3_6'

Tags: c, icu

Trying to get the ICU library to work with my C-program, so I can lowercase UTF-8 strings. Here's a minimum example that will reproduce the compile error:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unicode/ustring.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  UChar test[100] = { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x20, 0xc6, 0xd8, 0xc5, 0x20, 0xc9, 0x20, 0xc8, 0x20, 0xd1, 0x20, 0xca, 0x20, 0xd6 };
  for (int i = 0; i < u_strlen(test); i++){
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O3 -std=c99
GNUCFLAGS = -g -O3 -std=gnu99 -lm

main: obj/main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o bin/main obj/main.o

obj/main.o: src/main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o
```

**Compiler output**

```
gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -o bin/main obj/main.o
obj/main.o: In function `main':
~/src/main.c:9: undefined reference to `u_strlen_3_6'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I've tried including ALL the header files listed at http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ with no luck. Also tried adding `-licudata -licui18n -licuio -liculx -licutest -licutu -licuuc` to Makefile - same error.

I'm on Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie) and the following packages are installed:

- libicu52
- libicu52-dbg
- libicu-dev
- icu-devtools

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `#include <unicode/utypes>.` But you should be able to figure out which Unicode include file is needed by searching the header files to find which one has the definition of u_strlen_3_6.

You might also need to add a -I to your CFLAGS parameter in the makefile.

Comment: Include files solve compilation errors.  The OP had a link error.